# Dockerfile COPY command with three input parameters

Tags: docker, dockerfile, builds, nginx

I've encountered a Multi-stage Build example, where the first stage builds a ngnix server, and the second stage creates a ngnix service from that image.

The second stage looks like this:

```
...
# second stage
FROM scratch
COPY --from=build /etc/passwd /etc/group /etc/
COPY --from=build /usr/local/nginx /usr/local/nginx
COPY index.html /usr/local/nginx/html
...
```

This is a working example.

Now, notice the first COPY command. It received three parameters(!)

What is the meaning of 3 parameters in the COPY command? do you have a reference to documentation regarding this input?

Notice that the second COPY command uses 2 parameters, which I assumed are src and dest folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) the copy instruction may have multiple sources but only one destination.
Your first copy is coping two file `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` to `/etc`.

Comment: does installing `docker` from `snap` cause path problems with the `COPY` command?